# Why does a flex child with text-overflow and a scrollbar not expand in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, scrollbar, ellipsis

I have a scrolling `<div>` with a number of items in it. The items are set to use an ellipsis when they overflow. The whole thing is in an absolutely positioned container.

There are no limits on any widths, so the items should be able to fully expand, which they do in Chrome and Edge. In Firefox I get this:

[image]

I have seen many similar questions here, but the common solution is to set the flex child's `min-width` or `min-height` to something other than "auto". This **does not work** in my case (see code snippet).

I suspect that the scrollbar is the problem. If there are only two items to display, there is no scrollbar, but the box is still the same width.

How can I work around this?

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.scroller {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: gold;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}
.item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="item">a12345</div>
        <div class="item">b12345</div>
        <div class="item">c12345</div>
        <div class="item">d12345</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

is something like this okey?

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    min-width: 65px!important;
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.scroller {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: gold;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}
.item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="item" >a12345</div>
        <div class="item" >b12345</div>
        <div class="item" >c12345</div>
        <div class="item" >d12345</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the container has an explicit `width` set here, which prevents it from expanding or shrinking depending on the length of the items. This kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: mabye adding !important to min-width: ? why does min-width not work in your case?

Comment: `!important` is only useful for overriding (i.e., if `min-width` had already been set elsewhere). As for why it doesn't work... I wish I knew. It just has no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Firefox bug, which was reported all the way back in 2012 and it's still unfixed - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764076.

It's not limited to flexbox, it happens even with textareas and the workaround is to use `scrollbar-gutter: stable` for elements with `overflow: auto`. This adds a potentially unwanted empty space when the scrollbar is not in use, so it's best to limit this hack to Firefox only:

```
/* workaround for Firefox bug #764076 */
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  .scroller {
    scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  }
}
```

[MDN docs on scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter)